# Transaction in firebird 1.5

Tags: sql, transactions, firebird, firebird1.5, ibexpert

How to make transaction using IB Expert? I need a manual or something like

```
begin transaction
create table someTable(a int,b int)
insert into someTable values(1,2)
insert into someTable values(3,4)
commit transaction
```

but working in Firebird to see the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it after update or insert statement:

```
commit work;
```

Do it in a separate query